Expressing Schwarszchild coordinates with Cartesian coordinates
Im sure weve all seen the Kruskal-Szekeres diagram before (see below)
Im currently trying to draw this myself for a project, but Im struggling to understand Schwarszchild Coordinates. I tried reading through the wp page for it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_coordinates) but I honestly had no clue what it was expressing.
Im more or less looking for the simplest way to get t and r (and theta / phi, since some sources seem to reference those too?)
Im working with a digital environment in which I have to draw to the screen by defining operations at every x/y pixel position at a time (a shader). So I inherently need to convert from cartesian to schwarszchild coordinates.... and then use those in the definitions for the Kruskal-Szekeres Map. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates)
Can anyone help me out with this? Im honestly stuck and havent found many resources to draw this diagram.


Schwarzschild coordinates are spherical coordinates. If you're not familiar with them, that's they keyword you need to look for.

Thanks. So is r basically rho and t theta then? Like, which corresponds to which?

$r$ is the radius (which yes it's also sometimes written $\rho$) and $t$ is just time. It's spherical coordinates plus time.

The linked Wiki article on the “Schwarzschild Coordinates” actually describes the coordinates used in the Droste solution. The difference is in the definition of the radius. In the coordinates used by Schwarzschild, radius is defined as a spatial distance $r\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ while in the coordinates used by Droste, radius is defined as a reduced circumference of the sphere at that point. These definitions are different in a curved spacetime. For example, the spatial distance from the horizon to the origin is zero, but its “radius” in the Droste definition is $r_s=2M$.
